# Python:Expect an indentend Block

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am searching for hours but I can't find the mistake:

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/sDBtvLqb

I get the error:

```
Expect an indented Block
```

In  the most cases there is missing a Tabulator or similar but I cant find it?
Is anything other wrong in there which maybe cause the Error?
If I only run the class MyApp everything is fine. Only if I had the new Class "Manual_control" I get this error.

This is the working part:

```
class MyApp(object):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        self.root = parent
        self.root.configure(background='blue')
        self.root.title("Kranken Trage")

        self.frame = Tk.Frame(parent,background='blue')
        self.frame.pack()

        Uebschrift= Tk.Label(self.frame,text="Kranken-Transport",font = "Verdana 30 bold",fg="red").pack()

        btnRooms = Tk.Button(self.frame,text ="Räume")
        btnRooms.config(height=3,width=15,font= "Arial 40")
        btnRooms.pack(pady=5)

        Test = Tk.Button(self.frame,text ="Test Modus")
        Test.config(height=3,width=15,font= "Arial 40")
        Test.pack(padx=10,pady=5)

        btnmanualControl = Tk.Button(self.frame,text = "Manuele Steuerung",command=openmanualControl)
        btnmanualControl.config(height=3,width=15,font= "Arial 40")
        btnmanualControl.pack(padx=10,pady=5 )

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def hide(self):
        """"""
        self.root.withdraw()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def openRooms(self):
        """"""
        self.hide()
        subFrame = Rooms(self)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def openmanualControl(self):
        """"""
        self.hide()
        subFrame = Manual_Control(self)    

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def show(self):
        """"""
        self.root.update()
        self.root.deiconify()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("700x700")
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Line 98 should be right indented i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Manual_Control` class you did not indent the comments.

```
class Manual_Control():
"""
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    # other code
"""
    mcfenster = tkinter.Tk()
```

should be

```
class Manual_Control():
    """
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    # other code
    """
    mcfenster = tkinter.Tk()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a lot of errors. But I do not see any `Expect an indented Block`

But: function call in command `Button` before declaration (function of `openmanualControl`). You need to write:

```
btnmanualControl = Tk.Button(self.frame,text = "Manuele Steuerung",command=self.openmanualControl)
```

And `Manual_Control` is missing.

Comment: Line 8 starts with """ and end in the line 121.  the init is missing in the class.. I think you should reorganize the code.

Comment: Absolutely not! There are six ". The code presented is fine.